# How to build up a hash data structure

Tags: perl, hashtable

I am having trouble figuring out how to create several `%th2` structures (see below) each of which will be the values of `$th1{0}`, `$th1{1}`, and so on.

I am also trying to figure out how to traverse the keys in the second hash `%th2`. I am running into that error that is discussed frequently in SO,

`Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use`

Also, when I assign `%th2` to each key in `%th1`, I am assuming this is copied into `%th1` as an anonymous hash, and that I am not overriting those values as I re-use `%th2`.

```
use strict;

my %th1 = ();
my %th2 = ();
my $idx = 0;

$th2{"suffix"} = "A";
$th2{"status"} = 0;
$th2{"consumption"} = 42;

$th1{$idx} = %th2;

$idx++;

$th2{"suffix"} = "B";
$th2{"status"} = 0;
$th2{"consumption"} = 105;

$th1{$idx} = \%th2;

for my $key1 (keys %th1)
{
    print $key1."\n\n";
    for my $key2 (keys %$key1)
    {
      print $key2->{"status"};
    }

    #performing another for my $key2 won't work. I get the strict ref error.
}
```

Comment: The problem is that anyone looking at the question in the future will be confused as you've edited it to correct the error.

Comment: @ikegami Mea Culpa. Returned OP back to what it was and added code that would reproduce the error.

Comment: And I got votes to boot, but this post is a duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/18019278/using-same-hash-why-is-data-not-overwritten-after-hash-ref-assigned/18022667#18022667 and I've flagged it asking for moderator input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
$th1{$idx} = %th2;
```

to:

```
$th1{$idx} = \%th2;
```

Then you can create your loop as:

```
for my $key1 (keys %th1) {
    for my $key2 (keys %{$th1{$key1}} ) {
        print( "Key1=$key1, Key2=$key2, value=" . $th1{$key1}->{$key2} . "\n" );
    }
}
```

Or.. more explicitly:

```
for my $key1 (keys %th1) {
    my $inner_hash_ref = $th1{$key1};

    for my $key2 (keys %{$inner_hash_ref}) {
        print( "Key1=$key1, Key2=$key2, value=" . $inner_hash_ref->{$key2} . "\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: I had done that previously, but still cannot traverse the inner hash.

Comment: Updated to provide a more explicit example of inner loop use.

Comment: Perfect. I knew how to make it, and I'll go edit the OP to reflect your reference correction.

Comment: No need to edit the original question - it is easy to get confused with references at first with Perl, but with practice it will be become easy.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   $th1{$idx} = %th2;
   ```

   should be

   ```
   $th1{$idx} = \%th2;
   ```

   Only scalars can be stored in a hash, so you want to store a reference to `%th2`. (`%th2` in scalar context returns a weird string containing info about the hash's internals.)
2. ```
   keys %$key1
   ```

   should be

   ```
   keys %{ $th1{$key1} }
   ```

   `$key1` is a string, not a reference to a hash.
3. ```
   $key2->{"status"}
   ```

   should be

   ```
   $th1{$key1}{$key2}{"status"}
   ```

   `$key2` is a string, not a reference to a hash.